# WordPress, using child theme, how can I edit a function

Tags: wordpress

I am using `style.css` to "add" styles to theme- so it won't get overwrite when i update the theme.

How can i accomplish the same effect with functions?

Suppose i have a function (in the parent theme),

`function interio_gmap_shortcode($atts) {
....
....
$str .= '
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false**&language=iw**"></script>`

This is what i want to add- `&language=iw` , it's not exist in the parent theme.

- this function exist in `shortcodes.php`

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're properly [creating a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme), you should have your own folder with a `styles.css` and a `functions.php` in it.

To override a function like you're describing, you'll need to copy the php function from its original location (either your parent theme's `functions.php` or `shortcodes.php`) then make the changes you need in your child theme's `functions.php`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the parent theme was coded to allow the function to be overridden. If so, it will probably look something like:

```
if (!function_exists('interio_gmap_shortcode')) {
    function interio_gmap_shortcode($atts) {
    ...
```

In this case, you can copy the function to your own functions.php file and change it. At the time that the parent functions.php runs, your function will already exist and will be the one used.

If the parent function.php is **not** coded something like this, then copying the function to your function.php will result in a "Duplicate Function" error.

In that case, you would need to create your own function with a different name and use that instead.